# Advantage Database 8.1 SQL IN clause

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Using Advantage Database Server 8.1 I am having trouble executing a successful query.  I am trying to do the following

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE LastName IN ('Hansen','Pettersen')
```

To check for multiple values in a column.  But I get an error when I try to execute this query in Advantage.

*Edit* - Error

poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2115;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical element not found: ( There was a problem parsing the 
WHERE clause in your SELECT statement. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 46

And here is the SQL i'm executing

```
 select * from "Pat Visit" where 
DIAG1 IN = ('43644', '43645', '43770', '43771', '43772', '43773', '43774', 
'43842', '43843', '43845', '43846', '43847', '43848', '97804', '98961', 
'98962', '99078')
```

*Done*

Does anyone have any Idea how I could do something similar in advantage that would be efficient as well?

Thanks

Comment: Don't just tell us you got an error, show us what the error was!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `=` from your query?

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extraneous `=` in the statement after the `IN`.  It should be:

```
select * from "Pat Visit" where 
     DIAG1 IN ('43644', '43645', <snip> )
```